# New to mod_auth_ldap and looking for help

Tags: apache-2.2, ldap, mod-auth-ldap

Is there a way to configure mod_auth_ldap without modifying httpd.conf ? (ie. only using .htaccess files)

The reason I ask is that we are trying to setup a directory on our site to use ldap authentication (I do not administrate the ldap server, simply have credentials to connect.)  Additionally, I do not administrate the box hosting this project and am wondering if I can set this up without having to modify the main httpd.conf as this box hosts many many sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Apache 2.2 [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html#authldapurl) each directive has a *Context* line that tells you where you can use it. Most of the directives required to set the ldap module can be used on `.htaccess` files, so I think you can use it without any major changes to the site-wide config.

Answer (score 1):

Loading the module needs to be done in the httpd.conf or something included by it (not a .htaccess file), but everything else (enabling the module, setting up how it talks to the LDAP server, setting what users are allowed, etc) can be done in a virtualhost, <directory>, .htaccess, <location>, etc...

Note: mod_auth_ldap, mod_authz_ldap and mod_authnz_ldap are all different.  My experience is primarily with mod_authnz_ldap and mod_authz_ldap; I haven't used mod_auth_ldap in a long time.

Comment: The modules are loaded in httpd.conf but I did see a few places mentioning configuring more in httpd.conf.  Thanks.